# Работа с классом Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = in.nextInt();
```

Как я понял, в первой строке создается экземпляр in класса Scanner (используется конструктор по умолчанию). А во втором целочисленной переменной `N` при помощи метода `nextInt()`, который считывает первое введенное с клавиатуры число, присваивается введенное нами значение. Правильно ли я это понял? И что в первом случае означает запись в скобках в первой строчке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `nextInt()` считывает целочисленное значение из потока ввода. В данном случае это значение сохраняется в переменную `N`.

> И что в первом случае означает запись в скобках в первой строчке?

Для создания объекта `Scanner` необходимо указать для какого именно потока ввода он создаётся.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

В данном конкретном случае объект `Scanner` создаётся для стандартного потока ввода (клавиатура).

Comment: Спасибо, понял.